# Scraping Google

Tags: python, google-search, scrape, spynner

I am attempting to scrape Google search results as the results I receive using the API are not as useful as the results from the main site.

I am using the python requests library to grab the search page. However I am receiving an error:

`Instant is off due to connection speed. Press Enter to search.`

Is there any way I can disable instant search?

thanks

Comment: Directly Scraping Google Search Results is against their ToS...

Comment: When Google scrapes your website they won't accept your TOS either, right ?
Just don't accept their TOS, it's likely void anyway.

Comment: What about [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi?

Answer (score -2):

Python has a search api for python already, might save you some heartache.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

Comment: This is for the Google AppEngine database, to index and search on your own documents, and has no connection with Google Search